# Variable in Next.JS project has changed its value without assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've encountered some very strange behavior. I have a bigger project, but for demonstration purposes the following simple Next.JS application would suffice, I think.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a simple Next.JS project:

   `npx create-next-app my-next-app --ts`
2. Add following 2 files to the project:

```ts
// ./componens/logs.ts

export function createLogger(options: { name: string }) {
  const logIdObj = { logId: 0 };
  function vivify(o: { logId: number }) {
    let n = 0;
    Object.defineProperty(o, 'logId', {
      get: () => {
        console.warn(`Getting logId for logger ${options.name}: ${n}`);
        return n;
      },
      set: (v: number) => {
        console.warn(`Setting logId for logger ${options.name}: ${v}`);
        n = v;
      },
    });
  }
  vivify(logIdObj);

  return (message: string) => {
    logIdObj.logId += 1;
    console.log(`${logIdObj.logId}. ${message}`);
  };
}
```

```ts
// ./componens/Chat.tsx

import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { createLogger } from './logs';

const log = createLogger({ name: 'Chat' });

export default function Chat(): JSX.Element {
  log('render');

  useEffect(() => {
    log('useEffect');
  }, []);

  return <div>Some content</div>;
}
```

3. Modify the main page file `./pages/index.tsx` like this:

```ts
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Chat from '../components/Chat'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return <>
      <Chat />
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </>
}

export default Home
```

4. Run the project in development mode:
   `npm run dev`
5. Open the browser, navigate to `localhost:3000` and look what you'll get in console:

[image]

As you can see in `./componens/logs.ts` the access to the `logId` property of `logIdObj` object was intentionaly wrapped in getter-setter interceptors to log any kind of access to it, but according to logs value was changed without having been accessed.

Here is my environment:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
node: v14.17.0
npm: 7.22.0
```

and my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "my-next-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.30",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.4.4"
  }
}
```

I guess it might be related somehow to the internal Next.JS logic, but it should not work like this anyway.

As always, any help would be appreciated.

---

### **Update**:

Though first reply (thanks to [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763258/ben)) gave no clear answer to the reason of the issue, it gave a clue on what might be wrong. So I have modified `./componens/logs.ts` like this:

```ts
const allLogs = [] as { message: string, logId: number, time: number }[];
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // @ts-ignore
  window.allLogs = allLogs;
}

export function createLogger(options: { name: string }) {
  let logId = 0;

  return (message: string) => {
    logId += 1;
    allLogs.push({ message, logId, time: Date.now() });
    console.log(`${logId}. ${message}`);
  };
}
```

Now my results look like this:
[image]

Now we can clearly see, that rendering happened actually two times and `console.log()` doesn't always produce actual logs. Still, It's not clear why.

Any explanations?

Comment: Are you in dev environment? Do you have `StrictMode` enabled?

Comment: Sorry, I've confused typescript's `strict` mode with react's `StrictMode`. Actually, that was a right clue

Comment: I’m glad it led somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual reason was a specific behavior of React in `StrictMode`:

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console methods like `console.log()` to silence the logs in the second call to lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in certain cases...

For further explanations see https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Answer (score 1):

You're right. If you change:

```js
set: (v: number) => {        
  console.log(`Setting logId for logger ${options.name}: ${v}`);
  n = v;
},
```

to

```js
set: (v: number) => {        
  alert(`Setting logId for logger ${options.name}: ${v}`);
  n = v;
},
```

you'll see that the setter is, of course, getting called.

I don't have an answer for the underlying why - it might be a bug worth raising as an issue in the Next repo, or at least someone might be able to explain why.

Comment: I thought of it. So this time I'll do that